# populating field in access 2007 based on another field

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have data for tennis. I have two tables,(game_atp(Player 1, player 2, Name_T, **surface**) and tours_atp(ID, tournament, court surface)). In games_atp table i want to create a field **surface** and put the surface based on the tournament its played in( so based on Name_T), getting the info from tours_atp table.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a way to connect a row in game_atp to a row in tours_atp?  For instance, is `tours_atp.ID` the same as `game_atp.Name_T`?  There has to be a way to connect them.  Also am I assuming that `surface` will be equal to whatever is in `court surface`?  Assuming that `tours_atp.ID` is the same as `game_atp.Name_T` then you can just do...

`UPDATE game_atp Set surface = (SELECT court_surface FROM tours_atp WHERE tours_atp.ID = game_atp.NAME_T)`

This code will update all rows.  If you want to update only a specific game then you will have to use a WHERE clause and tell it the id of the game like so...

`UPDATE game_atp Set surface = (SELECT court_surface FROM tours_atp WHERE tours_atp.ID = game_atp.NAME_T ) WHERE game_atp.Name_T = '5555'`